# Make input background transparent and show flashing cursor?

Tags: html, css, input

```css
input[type="text"] {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus />
```

I'm attempting to make an input field with a transparent background but still have it show the flashing cursor so the user knows where to type. I'm close but it's not perfect:

- HTML: Makes the cursor blink on load. However this is not working on phones and it stops if you click the screen.
- CSS: Makes the background transparent (But still leaves the blue faded border when clicked?)

Is there a better way to do this or what's the best way to fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For point #1, if you want to have a fake cursor in the field at all times you'll need to do something creative with `js` or `css` animations.

I hope you understand that having a flashing cursor in the input field even when it's not in focus is breaking the user experience.

For point #2 just remove the outline on `focus`.

```css
input[type="text"] {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus />
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right about the user experience. I'm planning on adding a border when not in focus. Any thoughts on how to do that? thanks!

Comment: Just give a border to input[type="text"] and make sure to take it back off on focus

Comment: a simple blinking/flashing cursor with CSS: https://codepen.io/ArtemGordinsky/pen/GnLBq . `outline:none;` will give you a transparent input type.

Answer (score 1):

You are going in the right direction. Just add `outline: none;` property to your `input[type=text]` and you will have a transparent input field with no borders. The flashing cursor will still be there.

Here's your modified snippet:

```css
input[type="text"] {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus />
```

Answer (score 1):

to avoid the faded border add to your css code

```
outline:0;
```

and to make sure that the client's device will focus on the field wherever he tap or click add jQuery to your page header and add the following code to your Javascript

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
$("[name=fname]").focus();
});
```

Hope this help.